# Replacing Power Cord for Electric Chainsaw

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, cables

I have an old electric chainsaw, and want to replace the power cable as it has an old two pin fitting that doesn't match newer ones. I'm going to replace it with a three pin (I'm in the UK) plug that can then go to a regular extension cord. However, looking at which wire to buy, there's a lot more available, and cheaper, when it's twin core with an earth. The chainsaw is fully plastic cased, and doesn't currently have an earth or need one. Can I use the twin core cable and just leave the earth disconnected and trimmed back, or should I get cable without an earth - and why? Thanks!

Comment: A two pin fitting? *In the UK????*  I'm sorry but "electric chainsaws" and "UK allowing 2 wire *anything*" did not overlap in time.   The 2-pin thing indicates you have something quite different that is not made to run on normal mains.  Possibly low voltage or the UK's peculiar "110V center grounded" construction site power.  Again, not mains.  Maybe post a photo of the plug?

Comment: Two pin fittings are quite common in the UK for garden tools - they typically have a short cord from the tool with the fitting that then matches with a longer cord, which will then have the standard UK plug for an outlet. I'll find a picture and add that as a comment.

Comment: This for example pro elec pl09473 10A 2 PIN 0128-OR Connector Rubber - Orange https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/9790834977/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_i_7Y6T5F2EVJ7MXW4JXWWC?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you get "cordage", not "cable". There's a distinct difference.

Cordage is designed with a tougher but more flexible outer housing that's designed to take the punishment of being dragged around the garden and caught on tree branches and exposure to sunlight.

Cable, on the other hand, is designed to be permanently installed in the walls of your house. The exterior housing is designed to be smooth to be pulled through walls or conduit, but (basically) only once. It's not designed to take the day-to-day abuse that an extension cord or power tool cord will be subjected to.

To be honest, though, if the old plug is physically incompatible with newer sockets, I'd suggest you simply cut the old plug off and wire it to a new 2- or 3-pin plug, leaving the existing cord as-is. Unless, of course, the cord is actually damaged and needs to be replaced.

If you do replace the whole power cord, I'd strongly recommend going to an electrical supply house instead of a big-box retailer. They'll have the proper cordage for you, and will likely be happy to sell you just as many feet/meters of it as you'd like instead of forcing you to purchase a pre-packaged amount because that's what's stocked on the shelf.

Comment: Thanks - for sentimental reasons I do want to replace the whole cord so as to leave the original bit intact. That helps, but I'm still not sure on the earth :D

Comment: Earth/ground is a safety wire, and not needed for a circuit to work.  If an electrical device has metal casing/housing that yours hands/tongue can touch, it is very good to have.  Most recent devices have plastic housings now and ground is usually not needed to keep you safe.

Comment: I think 'cordage' must be another of those transpondian terms we don't use here in the UK. (We're building up quite a list of these;)) I've never heard of the term myself & a search for instance '10A 2-core cordage' give no results with the word included. I think we use 'flex' to differentiate from installation cable - but it's also round not flat & installation cable is stiff & holds bends, unlike 'flex'.

Answer (score 2):

For garden use, you want orange cable, so you can always see it.

You can get 10m of orange 2-core from [B&Q](https://www.diy.com/departments/time-3182y-orange-2-core-multi-core-cable-10m/188961_BQ.prd) for just a few quid. They also sell the 2-pin extension plug/socket combos too, if you need one.
Then it's just a case of putting the right 13A 3-pin on the end. Check the power requirement for the chain saw & fuse appropriately.

[image] [image]

Comment: This would be the "cordage" to which I refer. I was actually going to edit my answer to suggest buying an extension cord and removing the female end, which would do the same.